# How to sort a dictionary with two attributes in succession?

Tags: python, lambda

```
import operator

class Student:
        def __init__(self, name, grade, age):
                self.name = name
                self.grade = grade
                self.age = age


studi1=Student('john', 'A', 15)
studi2=Student('dave', 'B', 10)
studi3=Student('jane', 'B', 12)

student_Dict = {}
student_Dict[studi1.name]=studi1
student_Dict[studi2.name]=studi2
student_Dict[studi3.name]=studi3

for key in (sorted(student_Dict.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('age'))):
    print(key)
```

I want to sort it first by grade and then by age. I wanted help regarding the lambda notation.

Comment: Your code does not work: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'age'`. You cannot sort a dictionary like that. What you sort is keys, not values. And the keys are merely strings, they have no attributes.

Comment: You could use sorted twice to answer your question.  However, for lambda, see it as a "make_function" keyword.  It uses the list of comma separated value before the ":" as parameter.  That's really all there is to it...

Comment: @DyZ I added .values() and its works for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a create an anonymous function that gets the grade of the student and then the age in a tuple so you can use that tuple as a key to sort your dict:

```
for key in (sorted(student_Dict, key=lambda x: (student_Dict[x].grade, student_Dict[x].age))):
    print(key)
```